# Visual HTML editor in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Is it right that Visual Studio 2012 does not have a visual editor (WYSIWYG) for HTML, like Visual Studio 2010 had?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware Visual Studio 2012 does have a WYSIWYG editor. It's called the "Design" view.

Take a look at this Microsoft how-to guide:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9z74w20y.aspx

Comment: ok it works for html files but not for my razor templates :(